# How to filter records with non zero value in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-filter

I have a following array of records. And i want to exclude records with zero value. In this case, exclude only 'pqr' and get 'abc' and 'xyz' as output.

```
  $scope.myArray = [{
    name: 'abc',
    value: 2
  }, {
    name: 'pqr',
    value: 0
  }, {
    name: 'xyz',
    value: 104
  }]

  $scope.filteredRecords = $filter('filter')($scope.myArray, {
    'value': '!0'
  });
```

And the output filteredRecords contains

```
[{"name":"abc","value":2}]
```

But the problem is I don't want to exclude the 'xyz' record. I just want to exclude records with value exactly as 0. But it looks like angular is comparing substring not the complete value.

How do i use default angular filter to get records with non zero value 
**(without writing a custom filter)**

**[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ShBSiHiopSDkvo8K4DRb?p=preview)** for above code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As stated in [the doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter), you can use a predicate function instead of an array:

```js
$scope.filteredRecords = $filter("filter")($scope.myArray, function(value, index, array) {
  return value.value !== 0;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest just using `Array.prototype.filter()`

```
$scope.filteredRecords = $scope.myArray.filter(function(item) {
   return item.value !== 0;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `filter` method of javascript to do this:

```
$scope.filteredRecords = $scope.myArray.filter(function (item) {
      return item.value !== 0;
  });
```

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/varun1989/4ve8Lsz3/) is a working fiddle